# Can I overwrite a function in codeigniter to have different parameters?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically, I would like to have multiple versions of the same page, some which accept params, some which do not.

For example,

```
public function index()
{
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/sessiondata.inc.php');//sets up variables from session data
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/header.inc.php');//header
        include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//top breadcrumbs

        echo ' <h1>Let\'s sell an item, '.$username.',</h1>';


        //print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//bottom breadcrumbs
        require_once(APPPATH . 'views/footer.inc.php');//footer
    }
```

This is a default function for controller x.php, hypothetically. Can I also use:

```
public function index($item)
{
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/sessiondata.inc.php');//sets up variables from session data
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/header.inc.php');//header
    include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//top breadcrumbs

    echo ' <h1>Let\'s sell an item, '.$username.',</h1>';

    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE $item VARIABLE.

    //print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//bottom breadcrumbs
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/footer.inc.php');//footer
}
```

Will the system automatically know which version to use? Is there something similar to Java's @OVERRIDE that I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP doesn't allow you to overload functions in this manner. That said, you can achieve similar functionality by overloading the __call method:

```
public function __call ( string $name , array $arguments ) 
{
    if( $name === 'index' && sizeof($arguments) === 1 ) {
        // do index($item) stuff
    } else {
        // do index() stuff
    }
}
```

But to be honest, using __call in this manner is of no real value, and adds unnecessary  performance overhead, and complexity. In PHP, if you want to reuse code, simply decompose your functions into smaller discrete functions and reuse them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two separate functions (because PHP does not allow function overloading) but you can use a default parameter which CodeIgniter will honor when choosing controller functions. So instead of having two functions, do the following:

```
public function index($item=null)
{
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/sessiondata.inc.php');//sets up variables from session data
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/header.inc.php');//header
    include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//top breadcrumbs

    echo ' <h1>Let\'s sell an item, '.$username.',</h1>';

    if ($item !== null) {
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE $item VARIABLE.
    }

    //print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
    include(APPPATH . 'views/breadcrumbs.inc.php');//bottom breadcrumbs
    require_once(APPPATH . 'views/footer.inc.php');//footer
}
```